# retrieve content from markdown file and convert it to valid HTML code in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a documentation page and have some markdown files which represent the main content. I have a navigation sidebar where I can select the specific content.

When clicking on a navigation item I need to read the content from a markdown file. I have a method that returns me the required path but I don't know how to read the file.

Lastly I took `marked` to render the markdown syntax to HTML code.

I created a small example that shows what is missing

https://codesandbox.io/s/006p3m1p1l

Is there something I can use to read the markdown content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use VueResource to retrieve the content from your markdown file. 
Import the VueResource, and add it using Vue.use method (main.js):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import VueResource from "vue-resource";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

Then use `this.$http.get()` method it within your App.vue file to retrieve the markdown file conent. 
You can use markdown parsing library, like Showdown.js, wrapped within a vue.js method, directive or filter.

See: https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown and http://showdownjs.com/

There is also vuejs component wrapper for Showdown: 
See: https://github.com/meteorlxy/vue-showdown and https://vue-showdown.js.org/

In your case that should look something like this ( using vue-showdown):

```
<template>
  <div id="app"><VueShowdown :markdown="fileContent"></VueShowdown></div>
</template>

<script>
import VueShowdown from "vue-showdown";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: VueShowdown,
  data: function() {
    return {
      fileContent: null,
      fileToRender:
        "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rt2zz/e0a1d6ab2682d2c47746950b84c0b6ee/raw/83b8b4814c3417111b9b9bef86a552608506603e/markdown-sample.md",
      rawContent: null
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    //  const fileToRender = `./assets/documentation/general/welcome.md`;
    //const rawContent = ""; // Read the file content using fileToRender
    // this.fileContent = "### marked(rawContent) should get executed";
    this.getContent();
  },
  methods: {
    getContent() {
      this.fileContent = "rendering ";
      // var self;
      this.$http.get(this.fileToRender).then(
        response => {
          // get body data

          this.fileContent = response.body;
        },
        response => {
          // error callback
          this.fileContent = "An error ocurred";
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Check in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/poknq9z6q

If your markdown file load is one time thing, then you could import it data, just like you import the components, js files and libraries:

```
<template>
  <div id="app"><VueShowdown :markdown="fileContent"></VueShowdown></div>
</template>

<script>
import VueShowdown from "vue-showdown";

import MarkDownData from './assets/documentation/general/welcome.md';

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: VueShowdown,
  data: function() {
    return {
      fileContent: null,
      rawContent: null
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    //  const fileToRender = `./assets/documentation/general/welcome.md`;
    //const rawContent = ""; // Read the file content using fileToRender
    // this.fileContent = "### marked(rawContent) should get executed";
    this.getContent();
  },
  methods: {
    getContent() {
      this.fileContent = MarkDownData;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/xpmy7pzyqz

Comment: I upvoted it because it works but I don't know if this is what I'm looking for. Your first sandbox: I want to read a local file without using a http request. Your second sandbox: Sorry, I need to read it on the fly. So the import would happen within the `getContent()` function multiple times...

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with a combination of `html-loader`, `markdown-loader` & `v-html`.

First you need to install the loaders:

```
npm i html-loader markdown-loader
```

Then declare a computed property that returns an array with the names of the markdown files.

In data - add `showContent` and set the wanted default value - the init markdown file that gets loaded.

Then in the template - loop through the array and set the wanted markdown file on click.

Then finally, you can load your markdown files with a combination of `v-html` and template literals.

Example below:

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <h1>
            Markdown files
        </h1>

        <ul>
            <li
                v-for="item in docs"
                :key="item"
                @click="shownContent = item"
            >
                {{ item }}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div v-html="require(`!!html-loader!markdown-loader!../assets/docs/${shownContent}.md`)"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data() {
        return {
            shownContent: 'doc1',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        docs() {
            return [
                'doc1',
                'doc2',
                'doc3',
            ]
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

This way it's important to note, that the name in the array has to be the same as the markdownfile.